# How to disable object providing in debug_backtrace?

Tags: php, php-5.2, debug-backtrace

How to disable object providing with debug_backtrace in PHP 5.2.11?
debug_backtrace(false) didn't work.

Thanks in advance,

Simon

Answer (score 4):

It's quite late, but I would like to answer this. Actually this is not my answer, but I was also looking for solution for the same above mentioned problem and I found answer here on official site of PHP : [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php#119987)

Here, robert has gave brief description on using various options in `debug_backtrace` function.

```
debug_backtrace() - show all options
debug_backtrace(0) - exlude ["object"]
debug_backtrace(1) - same as debug_backtrace()
debug_backtrace(2) - exlude ["object"] AND ["args"]
```

I hope, this will help others.

Comment: This is probably not going to help in this specific case though, as OP was asking for a solution that would work in PHP 5.2.11. Those options above will work for PHP 5.3.6 or newer only.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP 5.2.11 [source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9a983f9ccfa61690fd2b0f186de12d4e8a28cab8/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L2120) indicates that `debug_backtrace` accepts a boolean parameter, so passing in `false` should work.

Comment: print_r(debug_backtrace(false)) still outputs an array with file, line, function, class, type, object, args and object is still filled :/